# Assigning one variable to another variable or a third variable

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Recently I came across this code snippet in python:

```
a = 'holy'
b = 'grail'
c = None
d = a or b or c

print(d) #prints holy
```

I thought that it would print `True`. Because `bool(a) = True`, `bool(b) = True`, and `bool(c) = False`, I thought this would simplify to `(True or True) or False` which is `True`. Yet, `d` is simply assigned to `a`. Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how python is working?

Can somebody explain exactly what's going on? Are the `or`'s just superfluous?

Comment: `a or b` returns `a` if `a` is `True`, else returns `b`. so i guess that clears things.

Comment: Could you please make your edits constructive, rather than just adding in a few backticks that make no difference to the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `or` chain returns the first *truthy* value or the last in the chain if all preceding values are *falsey*.

So, as the first name `a` contains a truthy value (empty strings are falsey BTW), the `or` chain returns that.

Try with `a = b = ''` and you'll find `a or b or c` to be returning `None` (value of `c`, even it is *falsey*).

Comment: This is odd behavior! I'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: @alec935 Not really. Think of the statement as `d could be equal to a, or it could be equal to b, or it could be equal to c`.

Comment: That makes much more intuitive sense. I'd add it to the answer

Comment: @alec935 Just as an addendum, you might also find the use of `and` interesting, as it will also return one of the values of the comparison, instead of True/False values. `d = a and b and c` actually returns `c` (which is `None` in this case).

Comment: Does it return the first Falsey value?

Comment: @alec935 Yes, it does, good observation!

Comment: @LucaBezerra `and` would return `c` even it were *truthy* (as its the last value). Just remember, `and` will return the first *falsey* value (as opposite to `or`) otherwise the last one (like `or`).

Comment: Using XOR seems to return the middle value. a = 0;
b = 1;
c = 0;
d = a ^ b ^ c;

print(d) #--> 1

Comment: @heemayl Yes, I didn't mean to say it would return `c` just because it was _falsey_ :)

Answer (score 0):

See @heemayl's answer for an explanation. In order to produce what you want, you could use `any`, which returns `True` if any value of the iterable is truthy.

```
a = 'holy'
b = 'grail'
c = None
d = any([a, b, c])

print(d) # Now prints True
```